# Failed to create record in SharePoint list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a record in SharePoint list but its not create.I don't know where is error in this code I am new in this plz help me with this I think in the issue in last line of javascript **GetListItemType** function

Submit Form
    
    
         
            
                Site Name
                
            
            
                Site Description

---

```
</table>
</body>
```

```
var listname ="TableData";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        saveSubmitForm();

    });

});

function saveSubmitForm(){
    var itemType=GetListItemType(listname);
    var item={
        "__metadata":{"type":itemType},
        "Title":$("#txtSiteName").val(),
        "Site_Description":$("#txtSiteDesc").val()

    };

    var requesturl =_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listname+"')/items";

    $.ajax({
        url: requesturl,
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers:{
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success:onSuccess,
        error:onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data){
        alert("Record Submit....");
    }

    function onError(error){
        alert('error'+error);
    }

}

function GetListItemType(name){
    return "SP.Data."+ name.charAt(0).toUpperCase().name.slice(1)+"ListItem";
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Show debugging details

Comment: What is the error message? Are you using correct `itemType`?